# zf2 How to achieve auto-complete when use fieldset

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-db

I have a web form generate by using zf2 fieldset, for one of the input field "Company Name" in this case, I want achieve auto-complete where the source for the select option comes from the database.

Thank for any advice in advance,

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

- Make this fieldset launch a jquery function when you type in
- This function will fetch data from an api controller in json
- The controller asks for the data and returned them as json
- one fetch you just have to display the data

You can do this using the jquery typeahead

- [Here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) is an example
- [Here](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me) is a way to implement it

Hope this will help you